# Alternatives to affirmative action in college admissions

Tags: united-states, students

Suppose that a university wants to preferentially admit students with backgrounds correlated with, but distinct from, a racial group. Assume that the university accepts federal funding, and so falls under the recent Supreme Court ruling [Students for Fair Admissions v. Harvard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Students_for_Fair_Admissions_v._Harvard). Could the university legally preferentially admit:

- Students recently descended from people who were enslaved? (e.g. a significant fraction of the student's ancestors as of 200 years ago were enslaved?)
- Students who speak specific languages, or specific dialects of English?
- Students who grew up in areas with low public funds, such as students who attended poorly-funded public schools in their K-12 education?

Assume for the sake of the argument that these admissions decisions produce outcomes which are racially correlated, but that students are not asked about their race when applying, and racial information is not considered when making admissions decisions.

I'm primarily interested in US federal law here. If these questions are not yet settled, any initial indications would also be of interest.

---

To be more specific, one could argue, for each of these admissions criteria, that they are proxies for racial criteria, and are therefore impermissible. One could also argue that a person of any racial background could fulfill any of the criteria, and therefore that they are fine.

How would a court decide whether criteria are illegal proxies for racial information, or sufficiently distinct to be legal? Are there cases that handle the question of whether certain information is a proxy for impermissible information?

Comment: A University can use virtually any criteria it wants, *until* its basis is found to be impermissible by a judicial decision.  Until a court rules otherwise (following a lengthy suit), **all** of the criteria you mentioned are not specifically banned.  *Some* of those criteria you described are likely to be determined to just be a proxy for race-based admissions, but only after a lengthy court fight. Until then, when they are specifically prohibited, an admissions board can use the criteria.

Comment: @abelenky I guess the question I'm asking is: What is the standard for finding whether or not an admissions criterion is a proxy for an impermissible criterion? I'll edit this into the question.

Comment: @abelenky Yes -- when someone asks about what a person may/can do on law.SE, the assumption is that they aren't asking about what is metaphysically possible, but rather about how a law applies to the given facts. There's not much gained by saying, "Shoot your wife in the face on Wednesday mornings isn't specifically banned. Imposing any punishment would require a lengthy court fight. Until then, you can shoot your wife in the face on a Wednesday morning."